# Extract elements from unknown number of lists containing JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to make chart component which will render data fetched from an API.
The response data is an array of equal length arrays that contain JSON-objects. Example:

`[[{ts:"2021-04-11 12:36:23", v:6}, {ts:"2021-04-11 12:38:23", v:8}, ...], [{ts:"2021-04-11 12:36:23", v:2}, {ts:"2021-04-11 12:38:23", v:7}, ...], ...]`

The timestamps of objects in one list will always correspond to the timestamps of objects in the other lists.

The chart component needs an array of n-element arrays of which contain a ts value and n other values, where n is the length of the response array. If the response array had a length of 2, the resulting list should look like this:

`[["2021-04-11 12:36:23", 6, 8], ["2021-04-11 12:38:23", 2, 7], ...]`

My problem is extracting this array. I have tried to destructure the response array to turn them into individual variables, which in turn can be iterated through with a foreach. I did not manage to make this work.

This is my current "solution":

```js
    response = [[{ts:"2021-04-11 12:36:23", v:6}, {ts:"2021-04-11 12:38:23", v:8}], [{ts:"2021-04-11 12:36:23", v:2}, {ts:"2021-04-11 12:38:23", v:7}]]
    response[0].map((e, i) => {
      const arr = [];
      date = new Date(e["ts"]);
      arr.push(date);
      arr.push(e["v"]);
      arr.push(response[1][i]["v"]);
      return arr
    ;})
```

This does not take into account that the response array may not have a length of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution:

```js
let output = [];
response = [[{ts:"2021-04-11 12:36:23", v:6}, {ts:"2021-04-11 12:38:23", v:8}], [{ts:"2021-04-11 12:36:23", v:2}, {ts:"2021-04-11 12:38:23", v:7}]]
for(let sset of response) {
  for(let item of sset) {
    if (typeof output[item.ts] !== 'undefined' && output[item.ts].length > 0) {
      output[item.ts].push(item.v);
    } else {
      output[item.ts] = [item.ts, item.v];
    }
  }
}
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up expanding on @sssurii answer. The chart component needed the data objects to have the same dimensions, so the Array is filled with empty strings to compensate.

Code:

```js
let output = [];
let temp = [];
let i = 1;
let dataLength = dataFetch.length;

for (let res of dataFetch) {
  for (let set of res) {
    let date = new Date(set.ts).toISOString();
    if (typeof temp[date] !== "undefined" && temp[date].length > 0) {
      temp[date].splice(i, 0, set.v);
    } else {
      temp[date] = new Array(dataLength + 1).fill("");
      temp[date][0] = date;
      temp[date].splice(i, 0, set.v);
    }
    output.push(temp[date]);
  }
  i += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the array of arrays, and map over each element in those arrays. And finally reduce them to a single array with the dates you are after.

```js
response = [
  [{
    ts: "2021-04-11 12:36:23",
    v: 6
  }, {
    ts: "2021-04-11 12:38:23",
    v: 8
  }],
  [{
    ts: "2021-04-11 12:36:23",
    v: 2
  }, {
    ts: "2021-04-11 12:38:23",
    v: 7
  }]
]
console.log(
  response.map(
    (l, _) => l.map(
      (e, i) => new Date(e["ts"])
    )
  )
)
console.log(
  response.map(
    (l, _) => l.map(
      (e, i) => new Date(e["ts"])
    )
  ).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
)
```